# Should I use a MySQL view or a report cronjob

Tags: mysql, view, cron

At my work my colleagues always build report cronjobs for heavy tables. With the cronjob we get all data from 1 day per user and insert the totals in a report table. The report overview page is not correct because it has a delay for at most 1 hour.

The cronjob runs 24 times a day (every hour).

Is it better to use a MySQL view? When a record has been added to the master table the MySQL view will updated, right? This is a very though action. Will that affect the users using the dashboard?

Kind regards,

Joost

Comment: The view is just a window to tables in the database. The database will still have to do the work of retrieving the result based on the view when ever the view is accessed. Sounds like their could be a lot of work for the database to do which could affect performance if the tables are huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so some terminology first.

The cron jobs are most likely appending data to existing tables (perhaps using an upsert method like INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE). These data you are writing to the existing tables may be indexed, just like normal MySQL tables, and they are also persistent on disk

Views, on the other hand, are really nothing more than saved queries in MySQL. Every time you open a view, you run the query again. Views aren't really useful for performance optimization as much as they are useful for small, efficient queries that otherwise might be a pain to remember. Views cannot have indices (although they are effectively saved queries, so the query itself can make use of the indices on the tables it's referencing) and they are not persistent to disk. Every time you load the view, you will be running the query that makes up the view again

Now, in between views and tables populated by Cron jobs, you also could install a plugin for MySQL called Flexviews (https://github.com/greenlion/swanhart-tools). Flexviews allows MySQL to use what are called materialized views (eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view).  Materialized views are basically views that are persisted to disk as tables. And, since they are tables, they can also use indices.

Materialized views are not native to MySQL, but the developer who maintains that plugin is well known in the MySQL community, and he tends to write good, reliable SQL tools . Obviously it would be a mistake to test the plugin in a production environment, or without using backups. But there are plenty of folks who use Flexviews in production to accomplish exactly what it seems like you'd like to do... obtain near real time updates of dashboard/summary tables in a way that doesn't murder DB performance.

I'd definitely check Flexviews out... you can learn more about it

here: http://www.percona.com/blog/2011/03/23/using-flexviews-part-one-introduction-to-materialized-views/

and here: http://www.percona.com/blog/2011/03/25/using-flexviews-part-two-change-data-capture/